# Cannot add web service reference to VS2008, works in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, visual-studio-2008, https, proxy

I’m having trouble adding a reference to an HTTPS web service using Visual Studio 2008, it works fine in Visual Studio 2010 but in VS2008 I get the below error.

Our IT guys tell me that the problem is that VS2008 is not using the IE proxy settings properly so the HTTPS request is getting sent to the HTTP proxy, which always denies all HTTPS requests. However, in VS2010 it works just fine.

They don't know how to fix this if that is indeed the problem.

(As an aside, I have to use VS2008 because I want to use this in an SSIS Script Task, however I've been testing this in a blank console app.)

There was an error downloading 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.asmx'.
The operation has timed out
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.asmx'.
An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.asmx. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: Also, I have asked the external vendor who provides the web service and they are able to connect using VS2008 without any difficulties. I will try it myself from home tonight in case it's just because they're on the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug in Visual Studio](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/405573/visual-studio-2008-service-reference-wizard-uses-http-proxy-settings-when-accessing-https-web-servicesk).